# Getting Null Value not sure why

Tags: arrays, powershell, import-csv

I am having this weird issue with my script. It creates the users just fine but when I go to add the group membership it seems to not be working correctly. It is very strange and I can't figure out why I am getting the null value errors.

```
$Path = "C:\T2\BulkUsers\AccountProvisioningTemplate.csv"
$CSVs = Import-CSV $Path
$Group1 = 'G1'
$Group2 = "G2"

$FirstNames = @()
$Initials = @()
$LastNames = @()
$FullNames = @()
$DisplayNames = @()
$EmployeeNumbers = @()
$TelephoneNumbers = @()
$SAMs = @()
$UPNs = @()
$Companys = @()
$Departments = @()
$Offices = @()
$Citys = @()
$States = @()
$Zips = @()
$Titles = @()
$Contractor = @()


ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $FirstNames += ($CSV.FirstName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Initials += ($CSV.Initials) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $LastNames += ($CSV.LastName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $FullNames += ($CSV.FullName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $DisplayNames += ($CSV.DisplayName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $EmployeeNumbers += ($CSV.EmployeeNumber) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $TelephoneNumbers += ($CSV.TelephoneNumber) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $SAMs += ($CSV.SAM) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $UPNs += ($CSV.UPN) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Companys += ($CSV.Company) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Departments += ($CSV.Department) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Offices += ($CSV.Office) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Citys += ($CSV.City) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $States += ($CSV.State) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Zips += ($CSV.Zip) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Titles += ($CSV.Title) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Contractor += ($CSV.Contractor) }

$FN = 0
$IN = 0
$LN = 0
$FN1 = 0
$DN = 0
$EN = 0
$TN = 0
$S = 0
$U = 0
$Comp = 0
$Dept = 0
$Off = 0
$C = 0
$S = 0
$Z = 0
$T = 0
$ConC = 0
$Con = "No"

$OU = "OU=General Users & Computers,DC=corp,DC=abc,DC=com"
$Password1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "Changeme123" -AsPlainText -Force

ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { New-ADUser -GivenName $CSVs.FirstName[$FN] -Initials $CSVs.Initials[$IN] -Surname $CSVs.LastName[$LN] -name $CSVs.FullName[$FN1] -DisplayName $CSVs.DisplayName[$DN] -EmployeeID $CSVs.EmployeeNumber[$EN] -EmployeeNumber $CSVs.EmployeeNumber[$EN] -OfficePhone $CSVs.TelephoneNumber[$TN] -SamAccountName $CSVs.SAM[$S] -UserPrincipalName $CSVs.UPN[$U] -Path $OU -Company $CSVs.Company[$Comp] -Department $CSVs.Department[$Dept] -Office $CSVs.Office[$Off] -City $CSVs.City[$C] -State $CSVs.State[$S] -PostalCode $CSVs.Zip[$Z] -Title $CSVs.Title[$T] -AccountExpirationDate $null -AccountPassword $Password1 -CannotChangePassword $False -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Enabled $True; $FN++; $IN++; $LN++; $FN1++; $DN++; $EN++; $TN++; $S++; $U++; $Comp++; $Dept++; $Off++; $C++; $S++; $Z++; $T++ }

Start-Sleep 2

ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { IF ($Contractor[$ConC] -Match $Con) { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group1 -Members $CSVs.SAM[$S]; Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group2 -Members $CSVs.SAM[$S]; $S++ } ELSE { $S++ } ; $CSVs.SAM[$S]; $SAMs[$S]; $ConC++ }
```

I am getting the error message and I am not sure why. It creates the users fine and when I put in a reference to $SAMs[$] it reports back the correct SamAccountName for the user in the CSV.

```
Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\T2\BulkUsers\BulkUserImport.ps1:69 char:120
+ ... roup1 -Members $SAMs[$S]; Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group2 -Members $SAMs[$S] ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGrou
   pMember

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\T2\BulkUsers\BulkUserImport.ps1:69 char:176
+ ... roup2 -Members $SAMs[$S]; $S++ } ELSE { $S++ } ; $ConC++ }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGrou
   pMember

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\T2\BulkUsers\BulkUserImport.ps1:69 char:120
+ ... roup1 -Members $SAMs[$S]; Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group2 -Members $SAMs[$S] ...
+                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGrou
   pMember

Add-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\T2\BulkUsers\BulkUserImport.ps1:69 char:176
+ ... roup2 -Members $SAMs[$S]; $S++ } ELSE { $S++ } ; $ConC++ }
+                    ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-ADGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.AddADGrou
   pMember
```

What is interesting is that if I comment out the user creation portion I get the correct SAM Account Names but if it runs I get nothing.

Comment: can you give me a example of whats in the text file

Comment: That's because the value of `$S` is larger than the length of the array, so `$SAMs[$S]` results in `$null`. You'll need to "reset" it around the same time you do `Start-Sleep`... but why are you making this so overly complicated for yourself? This could literally be one loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing an answer to give an example of code,

As Mathias said you are trying too hard, I don't know why you get the error but I believe you should do only one foreach with all attributes of the users.

The CSV file:

```
Firstname|Lastname|OU|SAM|Description|Password
John|Smith01|"OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"|John.Smith01|Test Account 01|Passw0rd
John|Smith02|"OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"|John.Smith01|Test Account 02|Passw0rd
John|Smith03|"OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"|John.Smith01|Test Account 03|Passw0rd
John|Smith04|"OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"|John.Smith01|Test Account 04|Passw0rd
John|Smith05|"OU=Users,DC=domain,DC=com"|John.Smith01|Test Account 05|Passw0rd
```

Code:

```
$Users = Import-Csv -Delimiter "|" -Path "C:\Setup\Users.csv"            
foreach ($User in $Users)            
{            
    $Displayname = $User.Firstname + " " + $User.Lastname            
    $UserFirstname = $User.Firstname            
    $UserLastname = $User.Lastname            
    $OU = $User.OU          
    $SAM = $User.SAM            
    $UPN = $User.Firstname + "." + $User.Lastname + "@domain.com"           
    $Description = $User.Description            
    $Password = $User.Password            
    New-ADUser -Name "$Displayname" -DisplayName "$Displayname" -SamAccountName $SAM -UserPrincipalName $UPN -GivenName "$UserFirstname" -Surname "$UserLastname" -Description "$Description" -AccountPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force) -Enabled $true -Path "$OU" -ChangePasswordAtLogon $false –PasswordNeverExpires $true 
}
```

Hope that helps you out and get your users up and running.
If you need Groups to be added also you can do that also with the Add-ADGroupMember/Remove-ADGroupMember commands.

Comment: I suggest to use [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1). Splatting makes your commands shorter and easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct code. Mathias please post a simple answer

> "That's because the value of $S is larger than the length of the
>   array, so $SAMs[$S] results in $null. You'll need to "reset" it around
>   the same time you do Start-Sleep"

So I can award you credit. I actually had a few errors. Like I double used the variable $S that has been changed to $SAM so not to conflict with State $S. Also my CSV was a little jacked up but the main problem was failing to clear the value of $S($SAM) that was the key. It is easy to forget to do that if you break code up the way I do.

Now I will have to google what Splatting is as its the first time I ever heard the term.

However I would like to take some lines to explain to all who are dismayed as to why I am making this so complicated. There are actually three distinct reasons.

1) I am not a super skilled powershell scripter. Yes I am not a noob trying to Write-Host "Hello World" but I am also not a programmer and clearly I am here to learn from gentlemen and ladies such as yourselves who clearly have more mastery in Powershell than I do.

2) Second, it is the way I think as a human being. I like to break down problems into pieces in order to solve them. I also like to assemble solutions as small pieces into a whole. I realize that although I can reduce my line count and make things more efficient by following your style at the end of the day when I need to pull items from scripts that were written months or years before, I don't have to work hard to decode the steps I have taken. I can see each piece and what it does as small groups of code. I admit I could probably pass through variables from the create user to the Add-Member or read from the CSV a little better but this is the very first time I am automating the creation of active directory accounts from a CSV so I had to learn how to do it in steps. I posted 1 previous question that helped me load CSV data into arrays. I also learned that I can reference CSVs data using column headings. The script was a great learning experience. Also its still not done I have to now add the Exchange provisioning steps so I also got to learn how to correctly load an Exchange session into my existing Powershell something I struggled with last year for weeks and never got quite right.

3) The third and final reason is that one day I may leave this job and I want the IT crew that comes after me (Who may not have the ability to script as I do) to be able to break this stuff into pieces and see the parts come together so that they can learn and maintain what I have written. Sometimes when I read code here I learn a ton (but I have a solid foundation in Powershell). Although I must admit that some of the code you guys write still seems like black magic to me as it is so powerful yet so simple at the same time. You gentlemen and ladies are very talented and I appreciate all the help you have given me. I hope to one day get to your level but I am actually not a scripter or programmer by trade. I am and Active Directory, Exchange, SAN, Virtualization, Citrix, and overall infrastructure engineer. I took to learning Powershell in earnest over the last year or so which means I am basically a toddler in the scripting game. I am trying to grow as much as I can and every little bit of your knowledge helps but I write all this to try and convince you to accept the fact that you guys are at a higher level then some of us and if you can accept that then maybe you can see why I haven't done what you would have in a given situation.

In any event here is my final code as promised

```
$Path = "C:\T2\BulkUsers\AccountProvisioningTemplate.csv"
$CSVs = Import-CSV $Path
$Group1 = 'G1'
$Group2 = "G2"

$FirstNames = @()
$Initials = @()
$LastNames = @()
$FullNames = @()
$DisplayNames = @()
$EmployeeNumbers = @()
$TelephoneNumbers = @()
$SAMs = @()
$UPNs = @()
$Companys = @()
$Departments = @()
$Offices = @()
$Citys = @()
$States = @()
$Zips = @()
$Titles = @()
$Contractor = @()


ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $FirstNames += ($CSV.FirstName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Initials += ($CSV.Initials) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $LastNames += ($CSV.LastName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $FullNames += ($CSV.FullName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $DisplayNames += ($CSV.DisplayName) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $EmployeeNumbers += ($CSV.EmployeeNumber) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $TelephoneNumbers += ($CSV.TelephoneNumber) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $SAMs += ($CSV.SAM) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $UPNs += ($CSV.UPN) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Companys += ($CSV.Company) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Departments += ($CSV.Department) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Offices += ($CSV.Office) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Citys += ($CSV.City) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $States += ($CSV.State) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Zips += ($CSV.Zip) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Titles += ($CSV.Title) }
ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { $Contractor += ($CSV.Contractor) }

$FN = 0
$IN = 0
$LN = 0
$FN1 = 0
$DN = 0
$EN = 0
$TN = 0
$SAM = 0
$U = 0
$Comp = 0
$Dept = 0
$Off = 0
$C = 0
$S = 0
$Z = 0
$T = 0


$OU = "OU=General Users & Computers,DC=corp,DC=abc,DC=com"
$Password1 = ConvertTo-SecureString "Changeme123" -AsPlainText -Force

ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { New-ADUser -GivenName $CSVs.FirstName[$FN] -Initials $CSVs.Initials[$IN] -Surname $CSVs.LastName[$LN] -name $CSVs.FullName[$FN1] -DisplayName $CSVs.DisplayName[$DN] -EmployeeID $CSVs.EmployeeNumber[$EN] -EmployeeNumber $CSVs.EmployeeNumber[$EN] -OfficePhone $CSVs.TelephoneNumber[$TN] -SamAccountName $CSVs.SAM[$SAM] -UserPrincipalName $CSVs.UPN[$U] -Path $OU -Company $CSVs.Company[$Comp] -Department $CSVs.Department[$Dept] -Office $CSVs.Office[$Off] -City $CSVs.City[$C] -State $CSVs.State[$S] -PostalCode $CSVs.Zip[$Z] -Title $CSVs.Title[$T] -AccountExpirationDate $null -AccountPassword $Password1 -CannotChangePassword $False -ChangePasswordAtLogon $False -Enabled $True; $CSVs.SAM[$SAM]; $SAM; $FN++; $IN++; $LN++; $FN1++; $DN++; $EN++; $TN++; $SAM++; $U++; $Comp++; $Dept++; $Off++; $C++; $S++; $Z++; $T++ }

Start-Sleep 2

$ConC = 0
$Con = "No"
$SAM = 0

 "`n`n"

ForEach($CSV in $CSVs) { IF ($Contractor[$ConC] -Match $Con) { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group1 -Members $CSVs.SAM[$SAM]; Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group2 -Members $CSVs.SAM[$SAM]; $SAM++ } ELSE { $SAM++ } ; $ConC++ }
```